# JAWS reading disabled span element

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am working with Angular js code which will enable a radio button dynamically in a span.

```
`<span data-ng-if="(!object.enabled || (form && !form.enabled))" class="rf-visuallyhidden"> Disabled</span> `
```

While testing with JAWS, JAWS is reading it as disabled although it is enabled on the UI.

Is there any workaround for the above issue.

Expecting JAWS to read the form fields correctly.

Comment: Can you try with aria-disabled ? I'm afraid that the disabled attribute can only have effect on actual form elements, but not custom controls, nor when put on the parent of multiple form elements to disable them all at once.

Comment: I tried using aria-disabled, didn't work @QuentinC

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are experiencing in JAWS is expected behaviour. Without a full example or test case, I can't be sure.

Perhaps I've missed the context of what you are trying to do, but it's worth explaining that the `disabled` state (e.g. `aria-disabled="true"`) is different from an element being hidden from an assistive technology (e.g. `aria-hidden="true"`).

Assistive technology software, such as screen readers, will experience elements that have a disabled state (yet remain visible), announced as "disabled". An example of this is a disabled button. Note that such disabled controls typically no longer receive keyboard focus. However, to hide a visible element from assistive technology software, you need to use something like `aria-hidden="true"`.